# Separating 5v and 12v circuits using diodes, converters, and switches

Tags: power-supply, diodes, buck-boost, step-down

I have drawn out a project with multiple power options.

**I am wondering if any of these reverse current protection diodes can be left out.**

**If the double pole double throw switch can be replaced by a double pole switch.**

**And if the boost converter can be left out in order to attempt to run the amp on 5v when the 12v is not connected. And can I just use 2 diodes to protect the 5v circuit when 12v is connected?**

**And if the boost converter is there, does it still need reverse current diodes?**

I circled in orange some sections that I think might be changeable.

[image: The orange sections contain possibly redundant protection.]

[image]

**More info**

One or all of these may be connected at once.

1.An internal battery in the form of a 5v portable power bank.

2.12v power jack.

2.Usb B used for midi but also supplying its 5v.

There is also a micro controller. So a need for somewhat clean 5v.

There is a amp that is 8-24v but could possibly work at 5v with low volume. Dirty power would effect sound quality.

When the 12v plug is in, it feeds the amp directly and feeds a 5v step down converter to power everything else.

Voltage drop from too many diodes could be a problem.

A 3 position switch is used to charge/disconnect/discharge the battery.

This is for a handheld musical instrument with a built in speaker. It could be desk mounted for long term use with battery disconnected or handheld with a portable battery and some about of sound over the internal speaker.

The amplifier used might be a bad fit but the choice was between one that was way too big or one that is almost definitely too small. At least the bigger one has better heat dissipation. They both cost under $2.

I hope have not been too wordy or trivial. I am just nearing the end of this project and I know that I might not even be going about it the right way. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear from your drawing if any of the converters are fully isolated.  If they are not, then combining grounds through diodes will be a problem.

Comment: Its a cheap component so I would assume it is not isolated if that is at all likely.

Comment: There are two main states. 12v connected by the plug and 5v connected by any other source. 12v feeds the amp, 5v feeds the other components. The boost converter sees a similar voltage on the output as the voltage it is attempting to reach. The other situation with no 12v plug. 5v is exposed to the output side, and 12v to the input side of the step-down converter. I don't know if it will feedback. Converting power down to 5v that is then boosted to 12. Or if the step-down will be saturated if that even is a thing.

Comment: And if connecting grounds through diodes, does that mean I should remove all the diodes on ground? I was trying to protect anything connected to the usb. Most likely thing connected would be a computer.

Comment: you really only need the diodes where two or more supplies are connected to one wire and you only need them on the positive side.

Comment: Another thing not clear - are there any negative power rails?  That is, are any of the converter + outputs connected to GND?  If not, then you probably can tie all converter input and output GNDs together.  Please post links to all modules (converters, amplifiers, etc.)

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001385782690.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.3.50e52835XQRr6u          https://www.aliexpress.us/item/1005001515717644.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.53.39a36bccLqWkNy

Comment: This boost converter does say it has isolation. And the stepdown converter only lists power as output so I am thinking it is only positive out. The ground just goes through. Also the stepdown says it has an Anti Reverse Diode. So it I guess has some protection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited schematic based on peoples advice.

I plan to set the boost converter to something like 10v.
With that, when the 12v amp is powered from a plug, the boost will not turn on.

I put a reverse diode back on the stepdown because in the event of it having forward voltage the wall wort providing 12v is powerful enough that this doesn't matter. The extra diode is there because I don't know or trust what diode was built in.

I am still a little reluctant to remove the switching diodes on the USB B input. I will try to test what I can with a multimeter. And maybe read into proper usb isolation.

I want to thank the people who commented. I was a little lost and the advice helped clear things up. I just knew there was the possibility that current could flow in a way I didn't expect and then destroy sensitive components.

[image]